# Python Mobile Test on AWS Device Farm (M2Crypto Issue)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, m2crypto

I'm working on Python Image Recognition test for Android devices. It works on local; but when I try to build it for AWS, I always get the following error:

> copying M2Crypto\SSL__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\M2Crypto\SSL 
>   running build_ext   building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
>   swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c   swig.exe -python
>   -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC -Ic:\pkg\include -includeall -modern -builtin -outdir build\lib.win32-2.7\M2Crypto -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i   error: command 'swig.exe'
>   failed: No such file or directory

I've already tried almost every solution I found on Internet but nothing changed. I'm using Windows 8.1 and Python 2.7

What should I do? How should I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Device Farm requires your python test should be able to execute on Linux_X64 platform.

You could create and package your test bundle on linux_x64 platform, then try to run it on Device Farm.

Comment: Thak you for your reply, I'll try it as soon as I can.